# How to mocking according to the received parameter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

According to the parameters that the method receives, desire to return something different. 
How to do it using the Mockito? 
For example, **according to the id of "Planilha"** I desire a different return but do not know how to make this equality.

My test

```
@Test(expected = InternalServerErrorException.class)
    public void testReadMetadados_invalidPlanilha_invalidFormat() throws Exception {
        oknok.validacao.entities.Planilha actual = new Planilha().setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"))
                                                                .setId("invalidFormat");
        planilhaReader.readMetadados(actual);
    }
```

My mock

```
@Bean
        UploadDAO getUploadDAO() {
            UploadDAO dao = Mockito.mock(UploadDAO.class);
            File myFile = new File(URL_TEST, "click/T001.json");
            Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setId("invalidFormat").setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"));
            when(dao.getPlanilha(Matchers.eq(planilha))).thenReturn(myFile);
            return dao;
        }
```

Comment: Your test is only expected to throw `InternalServerErrorException` currently. What would you like to it to assert?

Comment: The test is performed in error because of the mock.

Comment: My problem is `when(dao.getPlanilha(Matchers.eq(planilha))).thenReturn(myFile);` It isn't returned a file

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're testing. What different inputs do you want to pass and what do you want to assert for each input?

Comment: For example, if the "planilha" id is "123" wish the uploadDAO return file "123.xlsx" if id is "321" I want to return the file "321.xlsx". I don't know how to make these returns with the Mockito (because the comparison id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, but you should ensure that the `Planilha` class correctly implements the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method. This method should compare all properties needed for equality.

Answer (score 0):

I would first test it with Mockito.any first then if that works.

```
when(dao.getPlanilha(Mockito.any(Planilha.class))).thenReturn(myFile);
```

If this works then your equals method in Planilha is not implemented the way you expect it.

Also, your @Test method is expecting a thrown exception (expected = InternalServerErrorException.class), but your mock is not throwing one.  Just make sure your code will throw that particular exception and that that is what you want to test for.